# Emberjs increment a collectionView on condition

Tags: ember.js

I have an `ArrayController.create({})` that I have some dynamic data in it (data refreshed every 2 secondes) that I display with a collectionView in my template.

But I would like to not display some of the data from the collection sometimes. My `content` is an array of object, and in every object I have on value that tell me if I have to show it or not.

The problem is that I don't know how to specify my collection to not display this item, and just going to display the next one instead (if its possible to show it)

Here is my collection :

```
{{#collection App.ConferenceParticipantsView}}
{{#ifLead view.content.type}}
<td class="table-conf-td">
    <div class="conf-participant">
                <span class="conf-lead">
                    {{view.content.name}}
                </span>
        <img src="assets/ic_group@2x.png">
        <br/>
        {{view.content.phone}}
    </div>
</td>
{{else}}
{{#if view.content.waiting}}
<td class="table-conf-td" style="display:none">
    {{else}}
<td class="table-conf-td">
    {{/if}}
        <a {{action "conferenceParticipantActionBar" view.content.id}} style="text-decoration: inherit;">
        <div class="conf-participant">
                    <span class="conf-lead">
                        {{view.content.name}}
                    </span>
            {{view.content.waiting}}
            <br/>
            {{view.content.phone}}
        </div>
        </a>
</td>
{{/ifLead}}
{{/collection}}
```

The `{{#ifLead}}` is a kinda cheat I've done to verify some data (either display something different if the data has a lead value set a true.

So is possible to do something like this in the collection :

```
{{#if isShowing}}
    //Display the data
{{else}}
    //go to the next item
{{/if}}
```

Of is it possible to put a `display:none` on the `<tr>` tag generated by the collection if the isShowing value is set as false ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [each helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each) for that case. Check docs and examples.

```
{{#each model in XXXXXX}}

  {{#if model.canShow}}
    //Display the data
    {{model.name}}
  {{else}}
    // do not show anything
  {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```